# Writing a SIMPLE flask page using Keycloak OIDC

Tags: flask, keycloak, openid-connect

I have had a lot of trouble finding a concise example for what I need.

I have a working Keycloak server at https://auth.mycompany.com. (not the real company name, of course)
I have a flask server at http://testapp.mycompany.com.

All I need to do is have a simple page with a login flow that connects to my Keycloak server.  As it turns out, all the Keycloak extensions are abandoned and poorly documented. There is flask_oidc, pyoidc, etc.  However, the documentation I can find online is really not great.  I have looked through a lot of github repos and struggled through a lot of thickly-accented youtube videos, but have yet to find an example of a Flask (Django also acceptable) app that simply and concisely implements an OIDC login flow.  I even tried ChatGPT and it gave me several examples, none of which worked.  I understand the OAuth2.0 and OIDC standards, and have read their source documents, but I have utterly failed at finding a boilerplate implementation of these things to start my hands-on-keyboard work.

Can someone please, please show me a very minimal example of an extremely basic Flask or Django app that would connect to my Keycloak server.  I will gladly continue researching on my own to build upon it, but I can't seem to get it started.

I tried googling until I reached the edge of madness. I have tried numerous repos which literally did not function. I was told fictions by ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure folder is [here](https://github.com/tanthienqn/sample-flask-structure). In your keycloak server, you must create a client connect to have `client_id` and `client_secret_key`

**In server/constants/KeyCloakConstants.py**

```
KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL = os.getenv(
    "KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL", "http://keycloak/auth/"
)
KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME = os.getenv("KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME", "user-dev")
# client
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID", "client-service")
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv(
    "KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY", "jGlenvHtelkBtSS6zsi72prZQeoAmPxy"
)
```

**In server/extension.py**

```
from server.constants import KeyCloakConstants as kcl
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID

keycloak_client = KeycloakOpenID(
    server_url=kcl.KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL,
    realm_name=kcl.KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME,
    client_id=kcl.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret_key=kcl.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY,
)
```

**In server/services/KeycloakService.py**

```
from server.extensions import keycloak_client

class KeycloakClientService:
    @classmethod
    def login_user(cls, data):
        token = keycloak_client.token(
            username=data.get("username"),
            password=data.get("password"),
        )
        return token
```

In server/controllers/AuthController.py

```
from flask import jsonify
from server.services.KeycloakService import KeycloakClientService

auth_api = Blueprint("auth_api", __name__)

@auth_api.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login_user():
    """
    `param`
        :body:
            username: String
            password: String
    `return`
        :body: access_token, expires_in, token_type
    """
    data = request.json
    token = KeycloakClientService.login_user(data)
    return jsonify(output)
```

Here is only the sample for using keycloak in flask. In your server, You need more to handle all case such as when error request from keycloak, incorrect user